# How to achieve sequential execution of code containing both testing and asynchronous function calls

Tags: javascript, testing, asynchronous, callback, promise

I want to execute four blocks of code sequentially and conduct test during this sequential execution. The challenge is that the blocks contain calls of asynchronous functions.

I cannot seem to wrap my head around promises to use them properly and I just seem stuck after spending several hours on the block of code.

```
// Store current log of drone visits for DJI Phantom 4
db.query("SELECT COUNT(drone_id) FROM Drone_Visits WHERE drone_id = 2;", function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        current_drone_visits = rows[0]['COUNT(drone_id)'];                  
    }
});

it("should return status 200 (OK) when requesting route for this function", function(done) {
    request.get("/product/DJI/Phantom_4").query({brand: dji_brand, model: dji_model}).end(function(err, res) {
        assert.equal(res.status, 200);  
        done();
    }); 
});


db.query("SELECT COUNT(drone_id) FROM Drone_Visits WHERE drone_id = 2;", function(err, rows) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        updated_drone_visits = rows[0]['COUNT(drone_id)'];                  
    }
});

it("should increment the value of drones visited in the database", function(done) {
    console.log("A - " + current_drone_visits);
    console.log("B - " + updated_drone_visits);
    assert.equal(current_drone_visits + 1, updated_drone_visits);
    done();
});
```

What should I do here if I want to chain my callbacks such that they execute only after the previous function has finished?

Comment: To be sure I understand your question correctly: you want to run a query, then do a test, then run another query and then do another test?

Answer (score 0):

Use async.js if you are comfortable with callbacks, or use Promises, you can chain them in order to synchronise you functions.

just wrap your callback in a function that return a promise like this

```
    function P(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      db.query("SELECT COUNT(drone_id) FROM Drone_Visits WHERE drone_id = 2;", function(err, rows) {
        if (err) reject(err);  
        else {          
          resolve(rows[0]['COUNT(drone_id)'])
        }
      });
  })
}

function T1(data){
  //data in this case will be the result of the P() function 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{      
    request.get("/product/DJI/Phantom_4").query({brand: dji_brand, model: dji_model}).end(function(err, res) {
      if(err || res.status==200) reject(err);  
        resolve();
     });
  })
}

P()
  .then(T1)
  .then(...)
  .catch((err)=>{ 
    //handle error here
  })
```

sry for the bad formatting

Comment: Thanks, I'll play around with this code later and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do here if I want to chain my callbacks such that they
>   execute only after the previous function has finished.

This code does it for you:

```
describe ('test', function () {

    this.timeout(6000);

    it ('test', function(done) {

            var query1 = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {

               db.query("SELECT COUNT(drone_id) FROM Drone_Visits WHERE drone_id = 2;", function(err, rows) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(new Error('rejected query1'));
                    } else {
                        var current_drone_visits = rows[0]['COUNT(drone_id)'];
                        resolve(current_drone_visits);
                    }
                });
            })

            .then(function(current_drone_visits){

                var request1 = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {

                   request.get("/product/DJI/Phantom_4").query({brand: dji_brand, model: dji_model}).end(function(err, res) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(new Error('rejected request'));
                        } else {
                            resolve(res);
                        }
                    })
                })

                .then(function (res) {

                    try {
                        assert.equal(res.status, 200);  
                        return current_drone_visits;
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        done (err);
                    }
                })

                .catch(function(err) {
                    return Promise.reject(err);
                })

                return request;
            })

            .then(function(current_drone_visits) {

                var query2 = new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {

                   db.query("SELECT COUNT(drone_id) FROM Drone_Visits WHERE drone_id = 2;", function(err, rows) {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(new Error('rejected query2'))
                        } else {
                            resolve();
                        }
                    })
                })

                .then(function () {
                    var updated_drone_visits = rows[0]['COUNT(drone_id)']; 
                    var bundled = [current_drone_visits, updated_drone_visits];
                    return bundled;
                })

                .catch(function(err) {
                    return Promise.reject(err);
                })

                return query2;
            })

            .then(function(bundled) {

                var current_drone_visits = bundled[0];
                var updated_drone_visits = bundled[1];

                console.log('A - ' + current_drone_visits);
                console.log('B - ' + updated_drone_visits);
                assert.equal(current_drone_visits + 1, updated_drone_visits);
                done()
            })

            .catch (function (err) {
                done(err);
            })
        })      
    })
```

You can use the `this.timeout(6000)` to determine how long [Mocha](https://mochajs.org) will wait for your asynchronous code to complete. The default value is 2000 ms which may or may not be sufficient in your case.

Comment: I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined" in the first chain you resolve on then() where var request = new Promise(){...}.

Comment: You get the error message because my code "shadows" your `request` object and thereby tries to execute the method `get` on the `Promise`. That of course does not work. Correct it by changing `var request` to `var request1` and make sure that your own `request` object is within the lexical scope (e.g. in the global scope) of `var request1`.